# .NET: Common programming-keywords dictionary

Tags: .net, naming-conventions, naming, keyword

On [episode #162 of Hanselminutes](http://hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=180) they were talking about PowerShell, but more importantly around 04:50 they mentioned that PowerShell used something called **[The Common Engineering Criteria](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/cer/)** to have a **standard on which words to use** when developing new modules for it.

I cannot find any concrete dictionary on recommended words through this page.

**Does anyone know a good resource for standardized keywords** to use when developing .NET (C# in this case)? I'm talking **nouns** and **verbs**.

One good point they brought up in the podcast was that you could **almost alway guess what the object and methods is named**.

This to avoid not knowing which one of these to select:

```
object.GetInfo();
object.FetchInfo();
object.CreateInfo();
object.RetrieveInfo();
```

**UPDATE**: I found a good start, [a list of standardized verbs used in PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428.aspx), but they looks like the standards used in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Use the word that best describes what the method is intended to do...

object.ObtainByCircuitousMeansTheInfo();

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot the structure object.ObtainInfo()... thanks for adding another verb to the mess.

Comment: what about object.Info which is implemented by properties ;-)

Comment: Dario, not a good standard if the property-get needs to do something time-consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check out [Microsoft's Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx):

> Naming guidelines provide guidance on
>   selecting appropriate identifiers for
>   the elements that make up class
>   libraries including assemblies,
>   namespaces, types, members, and
>   parameters. Choosing identifiers that
>   conform to these guidelines improves
>   the usability of your library and
>   encourages users to trust that your
>   library will not require learning a
>   new set of conventions.

Most of interest to you would most likely be the section titled [Names of Type Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx):

> **Names of Methods**
>
> Do give methods names that are verbs
>   or verb phrases.
>
> Typically methods act on data, so
>   using a verb to describe the action of
>   the method makes it easier for
>   developers to understand what the
>   method does. When defining the action
>   performed by the method, be careful to
>   select a name that provides clarity
>   from the developer's perspective. Do
>   not select a verb that describes how
>   the method does what it does; in other
>   words, do not use implementation
>   details for your method name.

Beyond that its really up to you. You have a lot a freedom here but a good rule of thumb is to mimic the style of the names that you find in the .NET framework so that your types and members "feel at home".

Comment: Close enough, but not really what I was looking for.